# Why do access tokens issued by AAD contain information about the user?

Tags: azure, .net-core, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I read a lot about OAuth 2.0 and OpenId Connect and in theory I understand both concepts now.
But if I go into practice, some things are still confusing for me and I hope you can enlighten me in some way...
First thing is, that in all code samples how to secure a .net core API in an AAD-environment I find lines like this in the configure-section:

```
app.UseAuthentication()
```

and lines like this in the ConfigureServices section:

```
        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxx";
            options.Audience = "xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxx";
        });
```

However, to access my API I am not using an ID token, but an access token what is *Authorization*, not "***Authentication***" like in the code samples.
This works - but I do not understand it 100%.
So my first question is:

1. Is the access token also "authenticating" in some way?

The second thing:
I read that access tokens have no standardized format. They can be JWT or not, can have an audience or not etc. For this reason you could even put user information in the token like microsoft does. The access tokens contain claims like a "family name" or "given name" etc.
Id tokens in contrast have a standardized format to ensure that authentication is done in the same way by everyone.

If people are accessing my apis with an access token, I can read their name or e-mail address with "user.identity.name" for example. This value I can use to store the information *who* edited something or *who* inserted something.
So I am fetching information about the user with access tokens!
So my second question is:

2. Am I doing the right thing here? Or should this be done in another way.

and:

3. Should access tokens ever contain information about the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the access token also "authenticating" in some way?

Yes.
Your API is validating the access token when it receives it.
This is the authentication part, when your API verifies that the token signature is valid, came from the Azure AD tenant that you trust, that it is meant for your API and that it has not expired.

The authorization is when you check what permissions the token contains.
Your API can define different permissions that are given to client applications, allowing them different levels of access.
A valid token can pass authentication, but it might not pass authorization if it lacks the necessary permissions.

> Am I doing the right thing here? Or should this be done in another way.

Fundamentally your are doing the correct thing.
The token tells you who the user is that is using the client application, and if you need to know who it was who did something, that's the info you use.
However, if you really want to connect an action to a user, I suggest you use their object identifier / object id / oid instead of their name / username as those can change.
Unless you just want their display name.

> Should access tokens ever contain information about the user?

In the context of Azure AD, an access token will always contain info about the user if a client application is accessing an API on behalf of a user.
This includes authentication flows like authorization code, device code, implicit, and on-behalf-of.
They all use delegated permissions aka scopes to call APIs on behalf of the user.
Thus the token contains info about the calling app and the user.

If an app acquires an access token using the client credentials flow where a user is not involved, there will be no user info in the token.
In this case, application permissions are used instead of delegated permissions in Azure AD.
An application acts as itself, not on behalf of any user.

If your API supports both of these scenarios, sometimes the tokens contain user info and sometimes not.

The part about token formats is basically correct from a specification standpoint.
OAuth doesn't define a strict format for access tokens, while OpenID Connect does define one for ID tokens.

Using an access token to call your API is definitely correct.
The ID token is only meant for the app that initiated the user authentication, not for any APIs that it calls.
That's what access tokens are for.

Comment: Okay thanks for the detailed answer.. does this mean that Microsoft does not follow the open id and oauth standard? I'm reading everywhere that access tokens shouldn't be used for authentication... And why are id tokens needed at all by any application then? Couldn't I just have only access tokens in a Microsoft environment?

Comment: Well, technically speaking the client application isn't using the access token for authentication. From the point of view of the client app, the ID token is what it uses for authentication and the access tokens are what it uses for authorizing calls to APIs. But an API that receives an OAuth access token must of course validate/authenticate it. You can't authorize without first authenticating the token itself. The main purpose of the access token is to tell your API the calling app's permissions + user's roles (if applicable).

Comment: Though of course they have then included some details about the user in the token which would technically not be necessary for authorizing the caller, like the user name.

Answer (score 0):

if you check here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens
in the newer access tokens, by default it follows the standard of not having any personal information about the user. which is what the standards suggest, Access tokens should not contain much or any information About the user. rather just information for authorization (things that user can access). 
However you can always add the optional claims (and azure lets you do it) for personal info, but best practice suggests you shouldn't.

in terms of the addauthentication: Authentication is basically proving who you say you are. addauthentication(), basically calls microsoft azure ad to perform this task, saying hey aad please ask this person who he is, azure then checks and says ya this is a real person, but i won't tell you anything about him other than an id, and they have access to your api/application. So from your snippit, it's fine.

at this point, your serverside shouldn't have any personal information about the user, just that they have access and what scopes/roles. If it wants info about the user, it should then take that authorization (access token) and request it from whatever endpoint that token has access to (graph)

here's a great read about it: https://auth0.com/blog/why-should-use-accesstokens-to-secure-an-api/

Hopefully this helped clarify somewhat, and not add more confusion to the issue.

Comment: to be honest, it is a little bit confusing... Is this now contradictive to what juunas said? I will read both articles, but I am using a modern msal and did not change the standard or any default values. Anyway my tokens contain the user information... So what's true now?

Comment: its not totally contradictive, when he said it contains info about the user, as even access tokens need to contain a minimum amount of "personal" user information in order to identify the user to the webapi, eg. username or some equivalent.  the access token just shouldn't include info lie email address, country, etcetc that sort of information. and your token if its an access token it should not contain email. I admit microsoft cheats a little bit by including Name in the access token, which if you were to interpret strictly, it shouldn't contain technically contain that.